# Best 2D framework for unity3d

Tags: frameworks, 2d, unity-game-engine

I want to dev some 2D game for mobile using Unity3d (iPhone & Android) and realized that was a couple of 2D Frameworks on Assets Store, including some paid ones (like Uni2D) so, which of these 2D Framework you guys recommend me?
Thanks in advance =]

Comment: I think this question  would better fit in the Unity  forum as there is no chance to get clear  answer but many different opinions

Comment: You can try to check Cocos2Dx what is perfect for 2D game and app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2D Toolkit is the best i think.
It is very easy to use and learn.
And it supports colliders as well as custom colliders(polygon colliders) for 2d GameObjects(Sprites)
Sprite Animation is very easy using it.
The Documentation is very well and the support is great.
Try 2D Toolkit and i think you won't be disappointed.
Watch some youtube videos on it. You will get a better idea (or better read documentation about it)

(Source-Used 2D Toolkit in Game Development)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out for some good recommendations, [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/222386/which-framework-for-2d-game.html).

All the best with your game.